# How do I reset a result set so that I can loop through it again?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
$select = "select some_fiels from some_table";

$result = mysql_query($select);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
    {
               $rows = array();
               while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
               {
                 $rows[] = $r;
               }

               echo json_encode($rows);

               // THIS IN ORDER TO EXTRACT THE VARIABLE VALUE FOR USE LATER IN THE SCRIPT   
           while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
        $creator_member_id = $row['creator_member_id'];
       }
    }
```

But I am not sure what is the best way to reset the $result variable. Or does it need to be reset? What is the best way for me to extract the value into the $creator_member_id variable?

Thanks!

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated and not maintained for a while now. With PHP5.5 it will be flagged as "deprecated". Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: You already have the result in `rows`, just iterate through that.

Comment: @Musa would you know how that should look like since the items in the array are not simple items but mysql key-value results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the previous results, just do the query into a different array.

$result2 = mysql_query($select);

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0 )
```

It would help if you explained what you were trying to query though as I think you may be doing more queries than you actually need to do.

Comment: what do you mean do the query into a different array? How would that look like?

Comment: ah so you mean do two queries? Is there a way to just keep it at one query?

Comment: Probably, that's why I suggested that you provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: what I really needed to is just extract a value from the result.  It is just one row in the array, and I needed to extract the value of one of the fields in it.